# Proving $ \cot\frac{x}{4}-\cot x>2$, for $0< x < \pi$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

> Prove that: $$ \cot \left( \frac{x}{4}\right)   - \cot(x) > 2$$  for
> $0< x < \pi$.

$$\cot\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) - \cot(x) > 2$$
$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)} - \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} > 2$$
$$\frac{ \cos\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\sin(x) - \cos(x)\sin\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) }{\sin\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\sin(x)} > 2$$
$$\boxed{\begin{align}
\sin(a)\cos(b) &= \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a+b) + \sin(a-b)\right) \\
\cos(a)\sin(b) &= \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a+b) - \sin(a-b)\right) \\
\sin(a)\sin(b) &= \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)\right)
\end{align}}$$
$$\frac{ \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) - \sin\left(-\frac{3}{4}x\right)  \right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) + \sin\left(-\frac{3}{4}x\right)  \right)}{ \frac{1}{2}\left( \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) + \cos\left(-\frac{3}{4}x\right) \right) } > 2$$

$$\frac{ -2\sin\left(-\frac{3}{4}x\right) }{ \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) + \cos\left(-\frac{3}{4}x\right) } > 2$$

$$\frac{ 2\sin\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) }{ \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right)} > 2$$
$$\boxed{
\cos(a) + \cos(b) = 2\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)
}$$

$$\frac{ 2\sin\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) }{ 2\cos\left(\frac{ 2x }{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}x}{2}\right) } > 2$$

$$\frac{ \sin\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) }{ \cos\left(x\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) } > 2$$

$$\boxed{
\cos(a)\cos(b) = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\cos(a+b) - \cos(a-b)\right)
}$$
$$\frac{ \sin\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) }{\frac{1}{2} \left( \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) - \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right)\right) } > 2$$

$$\frac{ \sin\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) }{ \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) - \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) } > 1$$

$$0 < x < \pi \Rightarrow \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) - \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) < 0$$

$$\sin\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) < \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right) - \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) $$

$$\sin\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right) < \cos\left(\frac{5}{4}x\right)  $$

What can I do next? Maybe you have some other better way?

Answer (score 4):

Using tangent half-angle identities, by $t=\tan \frac x 2$, we have

$$\cot \left( \frac{x}{4}\right)   - \cot(x) =\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{t}+\frac1t-\frac {1-t^2}{2t}=\frac{t^2+2\sqrt{t^2+1}+1}{2t}> \frac{(t+1)^2}{2t}\ge 2$$

Indeed, for the latter inequality, by AM-GM or rearrangement

$$\frac{(t+1)^2}{2t}=\frac12\left(\sqrt t+\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)^2\ge 2$$

Comment: Thank you and from this proposal of mine something can be done.

Comment: As you see also from the alternative way, using $x/2$ as variable seems very convenient for this inequality.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(a)\sin(b) = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)\right)$ should be
$\sin(a)\sin(b) = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(- \cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)\right)$.

**Another way.**

We have
$$\cot \frac{x}{4} = \frac{\cos \frac{x}{4}}{\sin \frac{x}{4}}
= \frac{2\cos^2 \frac{x}{4}}{2\sin \frac{x}{4}\cos \frac{x}{4}} = \frac{1 + \cos \frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}},$$
and
$$\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}
= \frac{2\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - 1}{2\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos\frac{x}{2}}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1 + \cos \frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} - \frac{2\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - 1}{2\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos\frac{x}{2}} > 2.$$

Let $y := \frac{x}{2} \in (0, \pi/2)$. It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1 + \cos y}{\sin y} - \frac{2\cos^2 y - 1}{2\sin y \cos y} > 2$$
or (clearing the denominators)
$$1 + 2\cos y > 4\sin y \cos y, $$
or (squaring both sides)
$$1 + 4\cos y + 4\cos^2 y
> 16 (1 - \cos^2 y)\cos^2 y$$
or
$$1 + 4\cos y \cdot (1 + \cos y) (1 - 2\cos y)^2 > 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: As an alternative from here $$1 + 2\cos y > 4\sin y \cos y \iff \sin^2y+\cos^2 y + 2\cos y - 4\sin y \cos y>0$$
which is true indeed $$\sin^2y+\cos^2 y + 2\cos y - 4\sin y \cos y>(\sin y-\cos y)^2>0$$

Comment: @user It is better than mine. Thanks.

Comment: Just an alternative for the very nice alternative! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\cot(\tfrac x4)-\cot x$. We will sketch the graph of $y=f(x)$ on $(0,\pi)$. First of all, at the boundaries, $\lim_{x\to 0^+, \pi^-}y=\infty.$ To find the extrema we must solve $y'=0$. This gives the equation $2\sin(\tfrac x4)=\sin x$ which has a unique solution $(x^\star,y^\star)$ in $(\tfrac\pi 2,\pi)$ and it has to be a minumum. The problem reduces to computing $y^\star$ approximately. It can be done by using the Taylor series of $\cot x$ at $x=\frac\pi 2:$
$$\cot x=-(x-\tfrac\pi 2)-\frac13(x-\tfrac\pi 2)^3-...$$